# Riemann zeta function is analytic for $\operatorname{Re}(z)>1$

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory, complex-integration, riemann-zeta, analyticity

I want to show that, Riemann zeta function is analytic on the domain $\operatorname{Re}(z)>1$. I know that it is absolutely and uniformly convergent on the right half of the line $Re(z)=1$. Now, I am trying to invoke Morera's theorem to prove its analyticity, but I am not quite sure how  to do that. Can anyone help?

In general, if anyone can point me to some other direction then that is also welcome.

Comment: $z \mapsto \frac{1}{n^z}$ is holomorphic everywhere, so if you know that $\sum_{n=1}^k \frac 1 {n^z}$ converges locally uniformly on the right of $\operatorname {Re} z =1$, you know that its limit is holomorphic.

Comment: Yes, $a\mapsto frac{1}{n^z}$ is holomorphic everywhere and $\sum_{n=1}^k frac{1}{n^z}$ is uniformly convergent, on $Re(z)>1$, but why its limit is also holomorphic? I do not see that immediately..

Comment: @roydiptajit Uniform convergence of $\zeta(z)$ allows you to differentiate and integrate the series term by term in the region of uniform convergence.

Comment: @Targon  please let me know if my solution is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Otherwise it is immediate that for $\Re(c)> 1$ and $|s-c|<\Re(c)-1$, by absolute convergence
$$\sum_{n\ge 1}n^{-s}=\sum_{n\ge 1}n^{-c}\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac{((c-s)\log n)^k}{k!}=\sum_{k\ge 0} (c-s)^k \sum_{n\ge 1}n^{-c} \frac{(\log n)^k}{k!} $$

We need the whole analytic continuation of $\zeta(s)$ and the Cauchy integral formula to prove that the latter series in fact converges for $|s-c|<|c-1|$.

Comment: @ reuns can you please check if the first solution is correct or not..

Answer (score 0):

From analyticity of $\sum_{n=1}^k \frac{1}{n^z}$, we get that
$
\int_{\mathfrak{D}}\sum_{n=1}^k \frac{1}{n^z}=0
$, from Goursat's Theorem. Now, from uniform convergence of the partial sums, $\sum_{n=1}^k \frac{1}{n^z}$, to $\zeta(z)$ in $Re(z)>1$, we get

$$
lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\int_{\mathfrak{D}}\sum_{n=1}^k \frac{1}{n^z}=\int_{\mathfrak{D}}\zeta(z)=0
$$
Therefore, analytic.

Comment: What is unclear to you? $\int_C \zeta(s)ds=0$ implies that $\int_2^s \zeta(z)dz$ is well-defined and holomorphic thus analytic, and so is its derivative $\zeta(s)$.