# How to show Riemann zeta function $\zeta(s)$ is holomorphic (except at s=1)?

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta

The Riemann zeta function $\zeta(s)$ is known to be holomorphic, except at $s=1$.

I am not trained to university maths, but I interpret this to mean:

- it is complex differentiable at every point (smoothly changing values, no discontinuities)
- and is equal to Taylor series developed around any point in its domain

**Question: How do we show $\zeta(s)$ is holomorphic?**

Is it enough to show that the series which represent it, $\zeta(s)=\sum 1/n^s$ valid for $\Re(s)>1$ for example, are ***infinitely differentiable***, except at the known pole at $s=1$?

Is it also correct to say that by the principle of analytic continuation, any other series, such as $\zeta(s)=(1-s^{1-s})^{-1}\eta(s)$ valid over larger domains, are also holomorphic, except at any new poles. By separate analysis, there are no new poles in $0<\Re(s)\leq 1$.

Apologies if this question seems naive, I am self-teaching.

Comment: Recommendation:  Read about analytic continuation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation  and then come back to ask about anything still unclear.

Comment: hi @GEdgar I know you're trying to help, but that doesn't help me. Is it not as simple as proving the series is infinitely differentiable, except at one pole s=1?

Comment: Start by recalling local uniform limit of holomorphic is holomorphic, and the usual definition of $\zeta$.  Extend that to, e.g., the Dirichlet series $(s-1)\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{n}{(n+1)^s}-\frac{n-s}{n^s}\right)$ and then use reflection formula.

Comment: "Is it not as simple as..."   No, it is not.

Comment: hi @GEdgar from this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4032871/riemann-zeta-function-is-analytic-for-operatornamerez1 we have a comment "$z \mapsto \frac{1}{n^z}$ is holomorphic everywhere, so if you know that $\sum_{n=1}^k \frac 1 {n^z}$ converges locally uniformly on the right of $\Re()=1$, you know that its limit is holomorphic". This seems relatively simple enough. Have I deeply misunderstood ?

Comment: @Tariq That argument shows that $\zeta(s)$ is holomorphic for $\Re (s)>1$.

Comment: hi @Gary thanks for your patience with me (self-taught) .. so if it is holomorphic for $\Re(s)>1$ then by analytic continuation it is elsewhere, except for a finite number of singularities where we can find them. Is this correct logic?

Comment: @Tariq The basic thing is that you can come up with an expression that is a well-defined analytic function of $s$ for all complex $s\neq 1$ and it turns out that it agrees with $\zeta(s)$ when $\Re s >1$. Please read the answer by peek-a-boo below.

Answer (score 2):

Let $U=\{s\in\Bbb{C}\,:\, \text{Re}(s)>1\}$, and consider first $\zeta_0:U\to\Bbb{C}$ defined as
\begin{align}
\zeta_0(s)&:=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^s}
\end{align}
For each $\sigma>1$, if $\text{Re}(s)\geq \sigma$, then
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|\frac{1}{n^s}\right|&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{\text{Re}(s)}}\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{\sigma}}<\infty
\end{align}
This implies local uniform convergence of a series of holomorphic functions on $U$, and thus $\zeta_0$ is a holomorphic function on $U$. The only reason I use the notation $\zeta_0$ is to emphasize that we have not done any analytic continuation yet, so it's not the full Riemann zeta function yet. One has the following theorem:

> **Theorem.**
>
> There exists an analytic/holomorphic function $\zeta: \Bbb{C}\setminus \{1\}\to\Bbb{C}$ such that $\zeta|_U=\zeta_0$, and such that $s=1$ is a simple pole of $\zeta$ (with residue $1$).

We call the full mapping $\zeta$ the Riemann zeta function. $\zeta_0$ is merely a part of the restriction. As mentioned in the theorem, one has to *prove* that such an analytic/holomorphic function $\zeta:\Bbb{C}\setminus\{1\}\to\Bbb{C}$ exists. This is not a trivial thing (in general, existence of analytic continuations/extensions is a non-trivial issue), but in this case there are several well-known proofs of this theorem.

In the first part of my answer, showing the local uniform convergence of the series only shows that $\zeta_0$ is holomorphic on $U$. This says nothing about the existence of an analytic/holomorphic extension of $\zeta_0$ from the initial domain $U$ to $\Bbb{C}\setminus\{1\}$.

---

As I mentioned, there are several well-known proofs of the theorem. Here are two I remember off the top of my head:

- The first method can be found in Ahlfors. Start by observing that for $\text{Re}(s)>1$ (i.e $s\in U$) we have $\Gamma(s)\zeta_0(s)=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x-1}\,dx$. One can then deform the integration to get it as an integral over a certain contour $C$ which avoids the non-negative real axis, and then with a bit of work, one can show
  \begin{align}
  \zeta_0(s)&=-\frac{\Gamma(1-s)}{2\pi i}\int_C\frac{(-z)^{s-1}}{e^z-1}\,dz
  \end{align}
  (see Ahlfors for the details). Now, one observes that on the RHS, the integral is an entire function of $s$ (this is not trivial, but also not too hard if we have things like Fubini's theorem and Morera's theorem available). $\Gamma(1-s)$ has poles at $s=1,2,3,\dots$. In short, the RHS is a mermomorphic function on $\Bbb{C}$; but actually on the LHS, we already know $\zeta_0$ is holomorphic at $s=2,3,4,\dots$. In summary, the RHS provides us with a meromorphic extension of $\zeta_0$ to $\Bbb{C}$ with only a simple pole at $s=1$.
- Another approach for showing the existence of an analytic continuation involves using Mellin transforms and the Jacobi theta identity. Wikipedia gives [a formula for $\zeta_0$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Theta_functions). You can find more details in the delightful little book [A Brief Introduction to Theta Functions](https://books.google.ca/books/about/A_Brief_Introduction_to_Theta_Functions.html?id=cdyEAQAAQBAJ&redir_esc=y) (there are sections on Jacobi's identity, the Mellin Transform and the zeta function).

Comment: thanks @peek-a-boo. Your answer is clear for $\sigma>1$ but in my self-teaching I keep finding references to the need for the uniform convergence of the series to be on a compact subset of the complex domain. Why is this not an issue here? What am I misunderstanding. Once I've understood this I will mark this as solved.

Comment: @Tariq here we have a special situation where we have uniform convergence on a closed but not bounded set. This is an extra benefit. i.e we have something **better** than just uniform convergence on compact sets, so I'm not sure why you think this is a problem.

Comment: my apologies. We've established uniform convergence on $\sigma>1$ which is better than compact sets. However I can't find the logical step from this to say the series is holomorphic. My interpretation of the textbooks is that the link can only be made if the convergence is on a compact set. This is the source of my puzzle.