# Absolutely convergent series implies being an analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions, absolute-convergence

Consider the Riemann zeta function $$\zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{s}},$$
This series converges absolutely on $\text{Re}(s)>1$. I have seen in multiple literature that this implies that $\zeta(s)$ is an analytic function on $\text{Re}(s)>1$. Nevertheless, I don't see why this is the case. Since this is stated without any arguments in the literature, my guess is that this should be a general fact about complex series or products. In the sense that a complex series, or product, that converges absolutely on a certain domain, is an analytic function on that domain. Is this true? And if so, are there any easy arguments for this? Or a reference about complex analysis that discusses this phenomenon?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Mere convergence/absolute convergence alone is not enough. However, this series converges (absolutely and) **uniformly** on every compact subset of $\{s\in\Bbb{C}\,:\, \text{Re}(s)>1\}$ (by Weierstrass' $M$-test). It is the uniform convergence on compact subsets which preserves holomorphy/analyticity (see Morera's theorem in this regard). Henri Cartan's complex analysis text deals with convergence of sequences and series of holomorphic functions in chapter 5 (he doesn't deal with the Riemann zeta specifically, but the general theory is there).

Comment: See also [How to show Riemann zeta function $\zeta(s)$ is holomorphic (except at $s=1$)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4242553/568204)

Comment: @peek-a-boo The reason why I thought that absolute convergence would be enough, is that for the L-series of an elliptic curve, one only has absolute convergence on a certain domain. But besides not being uniformly convergent, it is still an analytic function on this domain. In which way is the analyticity obtained here?

Comment: Another reason why I thought it was enough was by the sentence "The above series is a prototypical Dirichlet series that converges absolutely to an analytic function for s such that σ > 1" on wikipedia.

Comment: I don't know about eliptic curves, so I won't comment on that. Regarding Wikipedia, I don't see how that sentence is (or gives the idea, or even claims to be) any form of justification for analyticity of the RIemann-zeta function on $\{s\in\Bbb{C}\,:\,\text{Re}(s)>1\}$. They're just saying $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^s}$ converges absolutely on $\text{Re}(s)>1$, and that in this region the sum is an analytic function; but the sentence doesn't say that absolute convergence (alone) is the reason for the sum being analytic.

Comment: I am sure that you could get analyticity if you write $\frac{1}{h}(\zeta(s+h)-\zeta(s)) = \int_{\mathbb{N}} \frac{1}{h}\left(\frac{1}{n^sn^h}-\frac{1}{n^s} \right)~\mathrm{d}\Gamma(n)$ for the counting measure $\Gamma$. Then try to find a bound to use Lebesgue's theorem in order to be able to pull the limit w.r.t. $h$ into the integral. Have not tried though, yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different approach (that I am not quite sure about, but should work): Let $A := \lbrace z \in \mathbb{C}: \mathrm{Re}(z)>1\rbrace$. Let $\Gamma$ be the counting measure on $2^{\mathbb{N}}$. Then, if $s \in A$ and $h \in B$ (where $B$ is a ball around $0$ such that $s+h \in A$), we have
$$
\frac{1}{h}(\xi(s+h)-\xi(s)) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{h}\left(\frac{1}{n^sn^h}-\frac{1}{n^s} \right) = \int_{\mathbb{N}} \frac{1}{h}\left(\frac{1}{n^sn^h}-\frac{1}{n^s} \right)~\mathrm{d}\Gamma(n).
$$
Observe:
$$
\frac{1}{\lvert h \rvert}\left \lvert \frac{1}{n^sn^h}-\frac{1}{n^s} \right \rvert = \frac{1}{\lvert n^s\rvert}\left \lvert \frac{1-n^h}{hn^h} \right \rvert
$$
We are interested in whether $\left\lvert \frac{1-n^h}{hn^h} \right \rvert$ is bounded on $B$. The only problem occurs when $h$ approaches $0$. Use l'Hôpital to get
$$
\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{1-n^h}{hn^h} = \mathrm{Log}(N)
$$
where $\mathrm{Log}$ is the logarothim's principal branch. So $\frac{1-n^h}{hn^h}$ stays bounded by some $C>0$. In total:
$$
\frac{1}{\lvert h \rvert}\left \lvert \frac{1}{n^sn^h}-\frac{1}{n^s} \right \rvert \leq \frac{C}{\lvert n^s \rvert}. 
$$
We know that
$$
\int_{\mathbb{N}} \frac{C}{\lvert n^s \rvert}~\mathrm{d}\Gamma(n) < \infty
$$
and thus dominated convergence yields (limit on the inside is just the derivative)
$$
\lim_{h \rightarrow 0, h \in B} \frac{1}{h}(\xi(s+h)-\xi(s)) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \lim_{h \rightarrow 0, h \in B} \frac{1}{h}\left(\frac{1}{n^sn^h}-\frac{1}{n^s}  = \right) 
$$
$$
\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{-\mathrm{Log(n)}}{n^s}.
$$

Please correct me if you have any objections. I am not quite sure, whether my l'Hôpital argument and my derivative in the last step work.