# A Question about Riemann Hypothesis

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, number-theory

This is not a personal question. I see people who are very confused by this question like me.

In short, I would like to ask that, which statement should we work on when trying to prove the Riemann hypothesis?

This?

$$\zeta_1(s) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s}$$

Or this?

$$\zeta_2(s) = 2^s.\pi ^{s-1}.sin(\frac{\pi s}{2}).\Gamma(1-s).\zeta_2(1-s)$$

(I denoted them $\zeta_1 and \zeta_2$ to distinguish)

Are these expressions exactly equal? It can simply be seen $\zeta_1(2) \neq \zeta_2(2)$. Consider we found a root of zeta function $r$. If we substitute the root into $\zeta_1(r)$, we will still get $0$? If not, what does $\zeta_1$ do? If $\zeta_1$ and $\zeta_2$ are different, why people introduce the $\zeta_1 $ to explain the Riemann Hypothesis?

Comment: $\zeta_2$ is an extension of $\zeta_1$. $\zeta_2(2)=\zeta_1(2)$. Really, you have not defined $\zeta_2$ here. But it can be done

Comment: The concept you need to look up to understand the statement of Riemann’s hypothesis is *analytic continuation*. It is the full zeta function which needs to be studied (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4242553/568204) for a very brief surface level definition… all the basics can be found in Ahlfors).

Comment: @Severus' Constant I really do not understand how did you evaluate that $\zeta_1(2)\ne \zeta_2(2)$

Comment: @GevorgHmayakyan $\zeta_1(2) = \frac{\pi ^2}{6}$ from basel problem. $\zeta_2(2)$ has a term $sin(\pi)$ which is $0$. Also  $\Gamma(-1)$ is has a pole. Product of these two should be undefined? Am I wrong?

Comment: @Severus' Constant I think if you try to use limit or series representation you will get the same result.

Comment: $2^s.\pi ^{s-1}.sin(\frac{\pi s}{2}).\Gamma(1-s).\zeta_2(1-s)=\pi^2/6+a_1(z-2)+a_2(z-2)^2+...$; where $a_1=0.937548...$, $a_2=0.99464...$; etc

Comment: And in reality there is no $\zeta_2(s)$ it is the same $\zeta_1(s)$